# What is the best way to import data into holochain from another source, like mongo?

Tags: mongodb, holochain, holochain-rust

#### MongoDB => Holochain Rust DHT

#### How to import, if possible

If I am using a different app backend, like mongo, and I get my holochain set up correctly and configured, is there a way to get the data from mongo to holochain?  How would I do that?

[Here is the question in context](https://chat.holochain.net/appsup/pl/dhpayzdyg7d1irmg8rece4z3go)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely technologically possible; you could write a nodejs script, fire up a Holochain container with the holochain-nodejs library, and import all the data as one agent. Then when users join the HC-based network, they vouch for their identity in some way and 'claim' all the data as theirs.
Here's a sketch of how it could look:

- you (let's call you 'agent 0') import all the data.
- For each user,  you create an 'anchor' with the user's ID (I'll explain anchors in a
  sec) and link each piece of data to the anchor.
- You also record that
  user's password hash as a private entry on your own source chain. A
  user joins the network and is required to prove continuity of
  identity.
- They do this by using node-to-node messaging to send their
  user ID and their password hash to you privately. You authorise them
  to claim their identity by publishing an entry that says that "agent
  public key x = user ID". (You would probably want to link from your
  authorisation entry to their user ID anchor and their public key too,
  for convenience's sake.)
- The user collects all their data by asking
  for all the links to their user ID anchor.
- The user then publishes
  each piece of their data to their own source chain as a way of
  'claiming' ownership of it.
- Now, every redundant copy of the data in
  the DHT has two authors in its metadata fields -- you and the user
  that actually owns the data. Peers validate that piece of data by
  saying, "Is agent 0 already the author of this piece of data?
- If so,
  has agent 0 published an authorisation entry that says that the new
  author of this data is allowed to claim/republish it?"

### Problems with this approach (not insurmountable):

- Agent 0 has to be online all the time cuz they never know when a new
  user is going to sign up and try to claim their data. Agent 0 has to
  import a ton of data. (I don't think it'd be vastly
  time-prohibitive though)
- For relational data, there's the chicken-and-egg problem of how to
  create links if the data doesn't exist. I'm thinking not of linking
  data to data -- that can be done on initial import -- but linking
  data to humans, who now have a public key which might not exist on
  the DHT yet because they haven't joined the network. That would
  always have to happen per-user once they join, and it could create
  some cyclic dependency problems.

### Anchors

Re: anchors, an anchor is just a pattern that consists of a base and a link -- the base is a simple string, so it's easy for anyone who knows the string to find it by hash. It acts as, well, an anchor to hang links off of. That's why I'm recommending using it to connect legacy user IDs to pieces of content. You can get sample source code for implementing the anchor pattern at https://github.com/holochain/mixins/tree/master/anchors (note that this is for the legacy version of Holochain, so it's written in JavaScript).

( answer provided by 
pauldaoust )